# Alamofire No Such Module (CocoaPods)

Tags: ios, cocoapods, alamofire

Using Xcode 7

I am trying to install Alamofire in a sample project. Have used the instructions from [Ray Wenderlich's page](http://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift)

Only change from above link is the podfile -- which is from GitHub page [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/swift-2.0) because the version has been updated. I have also used the Swift 2.0 branch.

Below is the snapshop of the error, my pod file and my terminal post installing the pod

[image]

**PODFILE**
[image]

**TERMINAL**
[image]

P.S: I want to use cocoapods to install Alamofire. I don't want to download it from github page

Comment: When you hit `pod install`, do you get Alamofire downloaded?

Comment: I think so..I have added the screenshot of my terminal in the original question..pls have a look

Comment: how did you solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one.

For Swift 2.0 there is no need to add Alamofire.xcodeproj into your xcode. Simply copy and paste source folder from https://github.com/Alamofire and you are done.

or if you want to install Alamofire from Cocoapods then try below code.

```
  source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
  platform :ios, '8.0'
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
```

Comment: tried the cocoapod bit of code..did not work...says cannot load underlying module for Alamofire

Comment: I think you must try the copy and paste of source folder from Alamofire git project into your xcodeprj. or try to update your cocoapods to latest version.

Comment: Yes..i did that and it worked..also I just needed to build the project even though the error was showing and then it was fine. thanks

Comment: Hi, I am extending Alamofire dependency as the same, but still getting "No such module" - My Xcode version in 7.2.1, OSX El Capitan etc. Please update as soon as possible.

Answer (score 76):

The Trick for me was to open the .xcworkspace file rather then the original project file itself.

Comment: Thats the first thing everyone should try. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 29):

working this:

```
Scheme -> Manage Schemes...

checked Alamofire checkbox　→　Build Alamofire scheme
```

and, if you used Playground , you should change settings Playground:

```
View -> Utilities -> Show File Inspector 

Platform OSX → iOS
```

Comment: It build successfully when selecting alamofire, but not working when I change my project.
And show build failed and no such module in Alamofire importing...

Comment: I was trying to run existing project developed using swift 2.0, on Xcode 9.2, and this solution has worked for me.

Comment: None of the solutions posted here so far work for me.

Answer (score 10):

import Alamofire after importing UIKit
Then comment it out, build the project first.
Uncomment it. 
(this worked for me, and others, when the other answers did not).

Comment: The other answers didn't work for me, I had tried everything and spent days trying to solve this. Perhaps for other readers this might help them. I have seen on another Q page re this exact problem that it was the solution for others too. It's not a magic trick, its a fix to a programming bug. Why not allow another solution? It's not repeating an answer in a thread, its offering another solution which might be the answer someone needs, and was not yet posted here. See here that this was the answer for several others: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/122

Comment: This worked for me just now after NOTHING else worked! Crazy

Comment: This works ... until the next clean. Then the problem is back.

Answer (score 5):

For reference to anyone who comes across this problem in the future:

**Swift 2.x + CocoaPods 1.x**

**Symptoms:** build works in Xcode for debug configuration but fails when `xcodebuild` is executed from console using `pod lib lint` or similar command. The result is `error: no such module 'X'`

**Solution:** 
In `MyProject.podspec` add your dependencies without specifying versions:

```
spec.dependency "Alamofire"
```

The `Podfile` should also contain the same dependencies. Then run:

```
$ pod install && open MyProject.xcworkspace
```

You should open `.xcworkspace` instead of `.xcodeproj`. The build will now work in both Xcode and console and `pod lib lint` passes validation.

I wrote this because I was trying to publish a new CocoaPods pod library and had a similar issue but found no answer and also because Google leads to this question.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what to do:

- close your project,
- install your pod library,
- then install alamofire.

After you do all things, don't open the file with extension `.xcodeproj` but open the file with extension `.xcworkspace`

Answer (score 5):

There is only one way to solve this issue.

> Quit Xcode.
>
> Delete project's temp files located at
> /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
>
> Delete ProjectName.xcworkspace
>
> Delete Podfile.lock file and Pods folder Run pod install.
>
> Open the newly created ProjectName.xcworkspace file and build.

credits to Dimitris Bouzikas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709912/error-could-not-build-objective-c-module-firebase)

Answer (score 3):

My problem was solved using these steps :

Clean Project 
Goto Project > Build Setting > Framework Search Path 
and add

- "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/Alamofire" as non-recursive
- $(inherited) as non-recursive
- $(SRCROOT) as recursive

Answer (score 3):

Have been facing the same problem, following trick resolved the issue

```
Go to Manage scheme -> Select pod library that is causing issue -> Build

Change back the scheme to project and then run the app, you are good to go
```

**Note**: If you don't see the pod library in the scheme, go to **Manage scheme** and select the pod library that you would like to build.

Answer (score 3):

Adding Alamo Fire to all of my target's build phases fixed it for me.

[image: Alamo Fire Link Binary With Libraries]

Answer (score 1):

After doing @satoshin answer, I also had to check the `Shared` box on the right hand side of the `Manage Schemes` window.

Answer (score 1):

go to finder locate the project and navigate to the '.xcworkspace' file. thats where your pods are installed. if you go to your original project '.xcodeproj' you will only the pod debug files. hopes this helps. took me a while to figure out the problem too.

Answer (score 1):

For me, solution was to exclude arm64 devices from Pods and Project.
Image is in attachment.

[image: Problem solved]

Answer (score 0):

I am using swift 3, I fixed this problem by deleting `Derived Data` for this project.
Cheers...!!!

Comment: I have cleaned derived data but still show same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If clean project/restart xcode/reinstall cocoapods etc, did not work. You can try running `Product` -> `Build for` -> `Testing (cmd + shift + u)`. The build failed but the import worked right after.

Answer (score 0):

As for me worked to change the name of the project. Accidentally put

> ProjectNameTests

instead of

> ProjectName

No schemas needed if you've configured the names correctly everywhere:

1. Check Podfile
2. Check which project file you've launched. 
   (The white icon should be created for "xcworkspace")
3. Product -> Clean Build Folder
4. Product -> Build (Now you can run in a simulator).
5. Start from the scratch, because most of the errors always occur in a cause of humanity mistake, not developers.
6. If you've put the wrong name for project in Podfile check "Linked Frameworks...". If so - delete this framework. The path is showed below at screenshot.[image]

Example of correct Podfile (Alamofire):

```
'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'ProjectName' do
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
end
```

- ProjectName should not contain any extensions(file types).

Answer (score 0):

[For future seekers] you could have missed the second step from the below :

Go to Project Setting

1. Go to **Build Phase** tab, create a new run script phase and add an input file to your Alamofire framework. In my case I set `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/IOS/Alamofire.framework`
2. Go to **General** tab, scroll down to linked framework and libraries add *Alamofire.Framework* folder. You probably won't find it from list so you need to press "Add Other" button and introduce it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For absolute newbie just close xcode project and open by the new way.
Choose in your folder file which contains extension like this: .xcodeproj and just enjoy you life.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by making sure you open the Xcode workspace file (with the extension .xcodeproj) instead of the project file (with the extension .xcworkspace). The workspace file contains dependencies installed by CocoaPods, and it is necessary to use it to work on your project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was because of Module Verifier setting. Switched it off. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/identifying-and-addressing-framework-module-issues

The error sounded like: `(fatal) could not build module 'Test'`