# Xcode can't find Alamofire, error: No such module 'Alamofire'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I'm trying to include Alamofire in my Swift project following the github(https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#cocoapods) instruction.

I've created a new project, navigated to the project directory and run  this command `sudo gem install cocoapods`. Then I faced following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/pod
```

After searching I managed to install `cocoapods` by running this command `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

Now I generate a pod file by `pod init` and edited it this way:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'


target 'ProjectName' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!


  # Pods for Law
    pod 'Alamofire'
  target 'ProjectNameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end


  target 'ProjectNameUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end


end
```

Finally I run `pod install` to install Alamofire. After that I open the project and `import Alamofire` statement gives me following error `No such module 'Alamofire'`

**Update-1:** Results of `pod install` is:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Alamofire (3.4.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
```

Comment: When you ran pod install, did you see that dependencies were installed?  Do you have a -bridging-header.h if needed?  If that process actually downloaded Alamofire, open the .xcworkspace which has been created.

Comment: I run `pod install` after editing the pod file. Result of `pod install` is given in the update.
So dependencies are installed properly I guess

Comment: Sounds like it.  Are you opening the .xcworkspace instead of the xcodeproj?

Comment: Tried opening both the xcodeproj and xcworkspace. Unfortunately neither works! :(

Comment: Do you see the pods with appropriate frameworks in your project?  Are they swift frameworks?

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the pod directory http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/05/23/5742bae352fc0.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112664/discussion-between-mostafiz-and-matthew-bradshaw).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alamofire No Such Module (CocoaPods)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466073/alamofire-no-such-module-cocoapods)

Answer (score 14):

Open the .xcworkspace not the .xcodeproj

Comment: Tried opening both the `xcodeproj` and `xcworkspace`. Unfortunately neither works!  :(

Comment: Hey! @gelSisaed check this [answer](https://github.com/imrajatgupta/Weather-Web.git) on SO for the proper explanation of why this works.

Comment: @imrajatgupta cool beans! Thanks for assisting.  But check the link

Answer (score 8):

go to Product -> Scheme -> Manage Schemes...
and check Alamofire true[image: sample image]
this work for me

Comment: great solution!

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes with no reason xcode can't load a module Alamofire. It can happen after a work session, after opening a project. The fix for this is to select a schema -> Alamofire, and run. If the message is "Successful", the schema can be changed back to project and it will work with no problems.

Comment: After trying heaps and heaps of suggested solutions, this actually worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to change your pod file like this below:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
 use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0' <<<----  Alamofire library is cross beetween projects

target 'NotifyM' do

end

target 'NotifyMTests' do

end

target 'NotifyMUITests' do

end
```

Another thing is `use_frameworks!` you should use this if the project is `Objective-C` based and try to use `Swift` pod library.

**UPDATE**: for the new cocoapods version 1.x the shared library should be like this:

```
# There are no targets called "Shows" in any Xcode projects
abstract_target 'Shows' do
  pod 'ShowsKit'
  pod 'Fabric'

  # Has its own copy of ShowsKit + ShowWebAuth
  target 'ShowsiOS' do
    pod 'ShowWebAuth'
  end

  # Has its own copy of ShowsKit + ShowTVAuth
  target 'ShowsTV' do
    pod 'ShowTVAuth'
  end
end
```

as indicated into cocoapods website :http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html

Answer (score 2):

you have to clean project and build, before you can import that library.

Comment: it should be in comment

Answer (score 1):

Install this way Pod file

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
 use_frameworks!

target 'NotifyM' do

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'

end

target 'NotifyMTests' do

end

target 'NotifyMUITests' do

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that and it's work for me :

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'App' do
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
  pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git'

end
```

After that, run : `pod install` in your project repository

Answer (score 1):

**2021 M1 USERS**

according to: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123614?answerId=683594022#683594022

- close XCode
- open Finder app and show there "Applications"
- right click on icon Xcode and click on "Get info" (or something similar)
- there is checkbox "Open with Rosseta" (or something similar). Select it
- run Xcode again and try to build

it worked for me hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks @Juan for answer, this worked on my M1 pro mac.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of efforts and all solutions provided above. I have fixed on Xcode 13.0:

**Use for Simulator:**
Go to:

```
- Build settings -> EXCLUDED_ARCHS = arm64
- Build settings -> VALID_ARCHS = arm64e armv7 armv7s arm64  x86_64
```

**Use for Realm Device:**
Go to:

```
- Build settings -> EXCLUDED_ARCHS = 
- Build settings -> VALID_ARCHS = arm64e armv7 armv7s arm64
```

Answer (score 0):

You should tap the Target to select Alamofire and build it once before coding.

Comment: I don't find any option to add `Alamofire` in `Target Dependancies` from `Build Phases`. Any suggestion please?

Comment: and if you do not see Alamofire in Target, you can click Manage Schemes to check it.

Comment: I don't find `Alamofire` in the Product->Scheme->Manage Schemes list. If I try to Add it doesn't shows `Alamofire`. If I try to import by clicking on settings icon it shows the `Alamofire` folder in the pod directory of the project. Is anything wrong there?

Comment: Tried opening both the xcodeproj and xcworkspace. Unfortunately neither works! :(

Answer (score 0):

When using Cocoapods to include dependencies always open your .xcworkspace

- In Podfile use `use_frameworks!`
- Remove any linked libraries from build phases.
- In Build Setting look for Framework Search Path and add `$(inherited)` in both debug and release.
- Do the same for Header Search Path too.

Now try a clean build.