# Swift 3: How to implement Cocoapods into project?

Tags: swift3, cocoapods

I'm a beginner to swift 3 and cocoapods and i want to implement this https://github.com/luowenxing/MTImagePicker image picker for my project.

I've installed the pod into my project and am using the .xcworkspace file.

However, I'm facing problems as i've errors like:

- No such module 'MTImagePicker'
- Use of unresolved identifier 'MTImagePickerController'
- Use of undeclared type 'MTImagePickerAssetsModel'

I've moved the MTImagePicker folder into my project as instructed.

But I'm still having this problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you so much!

Edited:

**Podfile**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'BPMatters' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

# Pods for BPMatters

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'MTImagePicker', '~> 1.0.1'

target 'BPMattersTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
end

  target 'BPMattersUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end





@objc protocol MTImagePickerControllerDelegate:NSObjectProtocol {

// Implement it when setting source to MTImagePickerSource.ALAsset
optional func imagePickerController(picker:MTImagePickerController, didFinishPickingWithAssetsModels models:[MTImagePickerAssetsModel])

// Implement it when setting source to MTImagePickerSource.Photos
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
optional func imagePickerController(picker:MTImagePickerController, didFinishPickingWithPhotosModels models:[MTImagePickerPhotosModel])

optional func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: MTImagePickerController)
```

}

```
    ///third party image picker////
func thirdPartyImagePicker(){

let imagePicker = MTImagePickerController.instance
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [MTImagePickerMediaType.Photo,MTImagePickerMediaType.Video]
imagePicker.imagePickerDelegate = self
imagePicker.maxCount = 10 // max select count
imagePicker.defaultShowCameraRoll = true // when set to true would show Camera Roll Album like WeChat by default.

//default is MTImagePickerSource.ALAsset
imagePicker.source = MTImagePickerSource.ALAsset
//imagePicker.source = MTImagePickerSource.Photos (Work on iOS8+)

self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

///third party image picker end///
```

[Screenshot of Terminal after pod install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVEDY.png)

**Solution: I got my stuffs working by doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39435421/7498313**

I marked Faris Sbahi's answer as the correct answer as I believe his answers can help beginners like me to set up the cocoapods and implementation of the project.

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: I'd recommend you find other pod for that as the latest supporting version of `MTImagePicker` is Swift 2.2. Anyhow, make sure you Clean (cmd + k) and then Build (cmb + b) before trying to import.

Comment: How do you see the version of the pods?

Comment: Most pods have a Requirements section in their readme (what you see when you enter the link you shared). He states it works on Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2

Comment: Oh... i saw 'iOS7.0+' and i thought that it's suitable for iOS7.0 and above.. Hmm.. I even tried this https://github.com/yahoo/YangMingShan and I can't make it work too :\

Comment: Make sure your framework is added in both Embedded Binaries and Linked Frameworks and Libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import MTImagePicker` at the top of your class.

Update your Podfile to

**Podfile**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'BPMatters' do
  # Pods for BPMatters
  pod 'MTImagePicker', '~> 1.0.1'

end 
target 'BPMattersTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
end

target 'BPMattersUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
end
```

After updating your Podfile to this, run `pod install` and ensure no errors are returned. After doing so, open the xcworkspace file and when you attempt to build ensure that the target is BPMatters.

Be sure that in the side pane you see something like this:
[image: Pods]

With a folder for MTImagePicker

Comment: i've done that and it's giving me the error of 'no such module'

Comment: You did pod install from terminal?

Comment: Post your Podfile please

Comment: I did what you said but i still have errors like 'No such module 'MTImagePicker'

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the class including the lines that are resulting in the error? You most definitely need to import MTImagePicker in that class if you're not already.

Comment: I've update my question. Most of the errors are like: 'Use of unresolved identifier 'MTImagePickerController' and
Use of undeclared type 'MTImagePickerAssetsModel'

Comment: I've imported the MTImagePicker and the error of 'No such module 'MTImagePicker'' is still there :\

Comment: I edited my answer again, let me know if you see that in your side pane.

Comment: Yup I do have the 'MTImagePicker' folder in there

Comment: Is the file in your project that you're adding the `import MTImagePicker` in your screenshot a member of the `BPMatters` target?

Comment: I've updated my question with the screenshot of the class' target

Comment: You've tried cleaning with cmd+k and restarting Xcode? Have you looked in Target > General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries and confirmed that the framework is present?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that too.. I've updated my question with the whole side pane of my project. The MTImagePicker.framework seems to be in red color, is that causing the problem?

Comment: One issue is that `Pods_BPMatters.framework` is red which indicates that something went wrong during the initial `pod install`. Can you confirm that there were zero errors or warnings returned after running `pod install` in terminal?

Comment: oh.... I've re-installed the pod and screenshot the results in my question.

Comment: Looks like it just now installed the pod. Is it still not compiling when you open the workspace?

Comment: Yeah.. it's still not compiling when i open the workspace

Comment: Could it be the version of cocoapod i'm using?

Comment: Possible. What version are you on?

Comment: PODS:
  - MTImagePicker (1.0.1)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - MTImagePicker (~> 1.0.1)

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  MTImagePicker: 5ed789c8d8783da3124ac7f8c5f717622d37e64a

PODFILE CHECKSUM: d32c5f7369652bee98e7fd78c6218ccd730448eb

COCOAPODS: 1.2.0

Comment: Is the version 1.2.0?

Comment: Sorry, I had to hit the hay. What ended up working for you?