# No such module 'Alamofire' in XCode 7.3 & Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I am integrating `Almofire` via cocoapods in my new swift project. After successful installation of Alamofire pod, i am unable to import it in my swift file. Xcode shows following error.

> No such module 'Alamofire'

Following is my `Podfile` for reference

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
 use_frameworks!

target 'CoreDataSample' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> '3.4'
end

target 'CoreDataSampleUITests' do

end
```

I have already referred following issues in Almofire on github

1. [Issue #551](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/551)
2. [Issue #1130](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1130)

Also tried following things

1. Project clean
2. Project Build
3. Removed Derived Data

Any advise would be appreciate.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project and building it again? Cmd+Shift+K, Cmd+B

Comment: Yes i tried it as well.

Comment: We had a similar issue before and on our end it was solved by making sure `Find Implicit Dependencies` was checked in our scheme we was running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466073/alamofire-no-such-module-cocoapod?rq=1

Comment: Ended up creating new project and fresh Pod installation worked. Thank you all for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this inside your pod file

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'demoAlamofire' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for demoAlamofire

  pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire'

  target 'demoAlamofireTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'demoAlamofireUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I hope this will help you.