# Xcode: No Such Module 'Alamofire'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest

I keep getting the error

> No Such Module 'Alamofire'

In my Xcode project swift file when using `import Alamofire`; the file is in a separate module within the project.

I have tried the following;

- Build and Run `Alamofire` Target
- Comment out import `Alamofire` and run project, then uncomment and build again
- Make sure I am using the `<MyProject>.xcworkspace` not `.xcodeproj`
- Use `$(inherited)` in project > Build Settings > Build Options > ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES
- Update Cocoapods, remove and reinstall dependencies

However when I open the inspector window for the swift file, the Target Membership has both the main app and the module boxes ticked.

[image]

When I untick the module for which the file is within, then in my `seperateModuleTests` file I cannot use the classes used in the swift file, as I get the error;

> Use of undeclared type

&&

> Use of unresolved identifier 'ClassName'

It seems when I uncheck the target membership for the swift file for the  class that is used for the tests, `seperateModuleTests` doesn't recognise the classes from the swift file. But when I check the the target membership for the swift file to be part of the separate module then I get the original error.

Can anybody help me on why this is happening and how I can resolve ?

Comment: did you add your test target configuration in your pod file?

Comment: No, not for the separate module.  I have for the project itself `target 'appTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end`

Comment: can you post your podfile content?

Comment: @ReinierMelian check the updated the question, thanks

Comment: Did you open the blue file with the `.xcodeproj` extension or the white file with `.xcworkspace`? You should open the latter...

Comment: @Honey as mentioned in my question I am using `.xcworkspace`

Comment: Sorry I was using my phone...If you've done all the above, then it always helps to do clean build, delete derived date, restart Xcode, mac...but I'm sure you've done those...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alamofire No Such Module (CocoaPods)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466073/alamofire-no-such-module-cocoapods)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are missing add `Alamofire` in your tests targets

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'AppName' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for AppName
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'Alamofire', '4.4.0'

  target 'AppNameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Alamofire', '4.4.0'
  end

  target 'AppNameUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
     pod 'Alamofire', '4.4.0'
  end

end
```

## Better would be

**You can also make a configuration with all pods that are commons to your targets**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.2'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

# Define main pods.
def main_pods
    #Your common pods here
    pod 'Alamofire', '4.4.0'
end

target 'AppName' do
    main_pods
    #add here other pods specific for this target
end


target 'AppNameTests' do
    main_pods
    #add here other pods specific for this target
end

target 'AppNameUITests' do
    main_pods
    #add here other pods specific for this target
end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: unfortunately the problem still persists, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Run a Clean: Product > Clean then a Build.

If that doesn't work. How is this being used? Is it for your own code, or is it another module that requires you to have AlamoFire?

Comment: It is in another module which requires importing `AlamoFire`

Comment: It seems the swift file in the separate module does not have access to the Pod dependencies