# No such module 'Alamofire' when archive the project swift4

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

Hello everything is working fine now, but when ever i try to archive the my project i am facing this error "No such module 'Alamofire" i don't know what happend followed many post on stack overflow but still facing same issue 
my pods

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'WithinRider' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for WithinRider
   pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'
   pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
   pod 'MRProgress'
   pod 'GoogleMaps'
   pod 'GooglePlaces'
   pod 'SwiftGifOrigin'
   pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'
   pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 3.0.1'
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
   pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
   pod 'AKMaskField'
   pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 13.2.0'
   pod 'BadgeSwift', '~> 5.0'
   pod 'SwiftyGif'
   pod 'PagingTableView'
   pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 5.0'


  target 'WithinRiderTests' do


    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'WithinRiderUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

error

```
No such module 'Alamofire'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32466073/5255016 refer this question. It might help you

Comment: There are many solutions provided to above question, just try them out.

Comment: i update my post

Comment: @Jhony First of all Remove **pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'** from the pod-file and then pod install deleter the derived data and archive data then add **pod 'Alamofire'** without mention version and pod install maybe it's works

Comment: Make sure all the deployment targets need to be the same, such as in the project file, in target, and the pod project as well.

Comment: i set deployment target 10.3 everywhere but still same issue

Comment: did you try @NikunjKumbhani's solution?

Comment: Also check if you have "Alamofire" in Embedded Binaries and in Linked Framework and Libraries

Comment: When using CocoaPods, it's necessary to start Xcode by opening your project's .xcworkspace file, instead of the usual project file. This is detailed in an answer to the question @Saurabh mentioned. Can you verify if you're doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the standard routine?

**1. Clean the project**

**2. Close Xcode, reinstall the missing pod, reopen Xcode**

**3. Build the project**

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while archiving. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499125/how-to-create-ipa-file-using-xcode) is a link for proper way of doing that. Sometimes it won't solve your issue. It didn't solve my issue as well. So I had to **Edit scheme**. Under **Achieve** I changed **Build Configuration** as I have several build configurations. And then try to re-archive the project.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by changing the POD and Project target deployment target as same.